# javascript window.open(): force to open windows for custom filestypes

Tags: javascript, window

I have clients that generates custom text files with the extention .in.

I have clients that generate custom text files with the extension '.in'.

The javascript code:

```
window.open(myurl/mytextfile.in, '_blank')
```

download the file instead of opening it in a new window.

knowing that I don't have control on this extension and that '.in' files are always simple text files, is there a way to force the browser to show a window with the text file in it rather than downloading it?

A the moment opens a blank window and shows a file save dialog for the downloaded file but it works with PDF FILES.

Comment: You need to set a header to tell it to open in the browser. You can set the `Content-Disposition` header to `inline` which will do the job. How you modify this will depend on your server configuration - you may be able to set up IIS/apache etc. to do this for `.in` files or you might want to write a custom handler for the URL.

Comment: Set Content-Disposition to inline in the server but browser still downloading instead of opening and than open a blank windows as well

Answer (score 0):

File extensions don't matter on the Internet. It is the `Content-Type` header that does.

Configure your HTTP server to set an appropriate `Content-Type` header (e.g. `text/plain`) for these files.

Comment: Set content-type to text/plain in the server but browser still downloading instead of opening and opens a blank window in background